# How to send enum in to some method in REST?

Tags: wcf

I need to write some method that can be called using REST ( using 'Post' ).
This method need to get two parameters 
        a- some enum 
        b- some int

Is it sending possible to send this enum parameters ? If it is so how can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find a sample for the above scenario:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetEnumValues/{id}")]
string GetEnumValues(MyEnum e, string id);

public enum MyEnum
{
     Fail = 0,
     Success = 1
}
```

Now the request looks as follows when performing the post from fiddler:

```
URL : http://localhost/Sample/Service1.svc/GetEnumValue/5
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: localhost

<MyEnum xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XMLService">Success</MyEnum>
```

NOTE: The parameter id is mapped as string as any parameter that is part of the query string needs to be a string type and then u can cast it to an int in your service implementation.

If you want to send both Enum and Id as part of request body then see below:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
string GetEnumValuesWrapped(MyEnum e, int id);
```

Now your requset looks as follows:

```
URL:http://localhost/Sample/Service1.svc/GetEnumValuesWrapped
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: localhost

<GetEnumValuesWrapped xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><MyEnum xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XMLService">Success</MyEnum><int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">5</int></GetEnumValuesWrapped>
```